# shorten string in an html string containing tags

Tags: javascript

Here's my problem - Given an HTML string (that I get from an element's innerHTML) containing a mix of tags and characters such as:

```
var s='first<font size="6">second</font>third';
```

I want to shorten the string to n characters ignoring the tags so that

```
shorten(13) -> 'first<font size="6">second</font>th'
shorten(7)  -> 'first<font size="6">se'
shorten(2)  -> 'fi'
```

Can someone recommend a good way to achieve that ? Thanks!
(at least a solution assuming no nested tags though a full one will be better)

Comment: Do you need to care about invalid/mismatched tags?

Comment: Not really as I'm taking the string from an element's innerHTML (I added that to the question now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a fast solution to your problem, it is just a linear traverse of your string avoiding to count those inside a tag (this function does not check for invalid/mismatched tags as Passerby commented).

You can work with this for a more functional/elaborated way

```
function shorten(str, top){
    var tag = false;
    var count = 0;
    var r = "";

    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(count == top) break;

        if(str[i] == '<') tag = true;

        if(str[i] == '>') {
            tag = false;
            r += str[i];
            continue;
        }   

        r += str[i];

        if(!tag) count++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Cheers :)

Edit: Changed little mistake of variable 'str' used as 's'

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
function browseChildNodes(childNodes, charsToRemove) {
    for (var i = childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[i];
        if (currentNode.childNodes.length == 0) {
            var thisText = currentNode.textContent;
            if (thisText.length >= charsToRemove) {
                thisText = thisText.substring(0, thisText.length - charsToRemove);
                charsToRemove = 0;
            } else {
                charsToRemove -= thisText.length;
                thisText = '';
            }
            currentNode.textContent = thisText;
            if (charsToRemove <= 0) return 0;
        } else {
            charsToRemove = browseChildNodes(currentNode.childNodes, charsToRemove);
            if (charsToRemove <= 0) return 0;
        }
    }
    return charsToRemove;
}

function shorten (string, maxCount) {

    document.getElementById('helpcontainer').innerHTML = string;
    var allText = document.getElementById('helpcontainer').textContent;
    var charsToRemove = allText.length - maxCount;
    if (charsToRemove <= 0) {
        return string;
    }

    var childNodes = document.getElementById('helpcontainer').childNodes;
    browseChildNodes(childNodes, charsToRemove);

    return document.getElementById('helpcontainer').innerHTML;
}
```

Run this jsFiddle for an example
https://jsfiddle.net/k59yam29/

Probably not as nice solution as MetalRider's, but works... You need a special hidden div for this solution, not very nice.